# CloudFoundary: got exception during init of a web-app which use mysql

Tags: cloud-foundry

I created a web app which use mysql. I used spring for the persistence.
Every thing worked on my local tomcat server.
I upload it into cloudfoundary, I follow the instuction and I create a mysql service and I use it
as a service for my web-app.
I try to run the app and I got the following exceptions:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate.create(StudentJDBCTemplate.java:19)
    com.tutorialspoint.Hello.doGet(Hello.java:58)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate.create(StudentJDBCTemplate.java:19)
    com.tutorialspoint.Hello.doGet(Hello.java:58)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate.create(StudentJDBCTemplate.java:19)
    com.tutorialspoint.Hello.doGet(Hello.java:58)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. Did you follow the steps on http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html? If possible can you file a ticket on http://support.cloudfoundry.com and then you can have a private communication with the official support team, sharing anything that useful for diagnosing.

Comment: Are you allowing Cloud Foundry to autoconfigure the datasource information for your application, or have you done anything in your code to directly setup the datasource information? Are you using VCAP environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is still there: there are 2 ways to configure a connection to CF services.

1) Taking the advantage of "auto-reconfigure". For any Java app, if it is using Spring framework, the doc here specifically described the details: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html

2) For Java apps, other than Spring apps, the details of connection to the CF provisioned services like hostname or password needs to be taken care explicitly. These can be retrieved by an environment variable named "VCAP_SERVICES". Simply this code snippet can achieve that:

```
System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")
```

After that set the properties to the connection configuration.